# Data is not passed into list by JpaRepository

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I'm trying to get data from MySql Database by custom jpql @query method. I'm not receiving any error, but my list of results is empty.

In console hibernate show results like this:

> Hibernate: select flight0_.id as id1_0_, flight0_.arrival_city as arrival_2_0_, flight0_.date_of_departure as date_of_3_0_, flight0_.departure_city as departur4_0_, flight0_.estimated_departure_time as estimate5_0_, flight0_.flight_number as flight_n6_0_, flight0_.operating_airlines as operatin7_0_ from flight flight0_ where flight0_.departure_city=? and flight0_.arrival_city=? and flight0_.date_of_departure=?

I tried to add annotations in model classes like @Column but nothing changed.

Typing lower or uppercase, still nothing. Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

**In this link you can see how my JSP pages, database table and view in the browser looks like** https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOeS3.jpg

```
@Entity
public class Flight extends AbstractEntity{



    private String flightNumber;
    private String operatingAirlines;
    private String departureCity;
    private String arrivalCity;
    private Date dateOfDeparture;
    private Timestamp estimatedDepartureTime;
```

Below are getters and setters for those fields.

```
public interface FlightRepository extends JpaRepository<Flight, Long> {

    @Query("from Flight where departureCity=:departureCity and arrivalCity=:arrivalCity and dateOfDeparture=:dateOfDeparture")
    List<Flight> findFlights(@Param("departureCity") String from, @Param("arrivalCity") String to, 
            @Param("dateOfDeparture") Date departureDate);


}
```

```
@Controller
public class FlightController {

    @Autowired
    FlightRepository flightRepository;

    @RequestMapping("findFlights")
    public String findFlights(@RequestParam("from") String from,@RequestParam("to") String to,
            @RequestParam("departureDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM-dd-yyyy") Date departureDate, ModelMap modelMap) 
    {
        List<Flight> findFlights = flightRepository.findFlights(from, to, departureDate);
        modelMap.addAttribute("flights",findFlights);

        for (Flight flightTMP : findFlights) {
            System.out.println(flightTMP);
        }
        return "displayFlights";
    }
}
```

Comment: I see no proof that there is a problem. A query is invoked, it has zero results - that's a valid outcome. The important part in that query are the three parameters (departure_city, arrival_city and date_of_departure). You need to know the values being input there so you can put them in the SQL query and invoke it against the database. Likely, it will come up with zero results because there is some mismatch in a city name for example.

Comment: With regular sql I got results. I tried to type from: AUS to: NYC with date 02-05-2018 and as previous 0 results, but with date 02-06-2018 i got wanted results. Still got no idea why with different date works (it's only 1 day difference). When i type 02-06-2018 i got results for day previous, when write 02-07-2018 receive results for 02-06-2018 (day back)

Comment: Few questions. Is the table got created by hibernate or you created it manually? If you created the table manually, could please post the screen shot of column datatypes as well. 
Are both Database and your application server running in the same timezone?
To replicate the issue, I've used your code with in-memory H2 database with Spring-boot and its working fine.

Comment: I created DB (tables and inserted values ) manually by sql.script. I dont know how to check the timezones. And application is created in Spring-tool-suite. I'm launching it by run as "Spring boot app".  https://imgur.com/a/AmWxQ9A

Comment: I had to change in database url part about Timezone and now it works as it should. Thanks @Ramu for told my about timezones.